# RegExp Find and Replace

Tags: regex, swift, swift3

I'm trying to resolve a problem with Swift 3 but with no success.

I must change this string :

```
< iframe class="giphy-embed" src="//giphy.com/embed/akEhceCKfMyKA"></iframe>
```

with this one :

```
< img class="giphy-embed" src="https://media.giphy.com/media/akEhceCKfMyKA/giphy.gif"></img>
```

The node name must change from **'iframe'** to **'img'**. Also I must keep a part of link and change the beginning and the end

"//giphy.com/embed/**akEhceCKfMyKA**"

to "https://media.giphy.com/media/**akEhceCKfMyKA**/giphy.gif"

Have you a solution with a regular expression ?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how you do it in Swift. `NSRegularExpression` still works with `NSString / NSMutableString` so it's easier if you convert it before hand.

```
let str = "< iframe class=\"giphy-embed\" src=\"//giphy.com/embed/akEhceCKfMyKA\"></iframe>"
let mutableStr = NSMutableString(string: str)

let regex = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: "<\\s*(iframe).+src=\"(.+?)\".+", options: [])
if let match = regex.firstMatch(in: str, options: [], range: NSMakeRange(0, mutableStr.length)) {
    let components = mutableStr.substring(with: match.rangeAt(2)).components(separatedBy: "/")
    let newURL = "https://media.giphy.com/media/" + components.last! + "/giphy.gif"

    mutableStr.replaceCharacters(in: match.rangeAt(2), with: newURL)
    mutableStr.replaceCharacters(in: match.rangeAt(1), with: "image")
}

let newStr = mutableStr as String
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. You save my day. I've got a question. Why do you use NSMutableString ?

Comment: Because `NSRegularExpresion` still works better with string. Noticed `rangeAtIddex(_)` returns an `NSRange`? That's how subscript a string in `NSString / NSMutableString` but not Swift's `String`

Comment: Thanks for your explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Find:

```
< iframe (class="giphy-embed" src=")\/\/giphy\.com\/embed\/([A-Za-z]*)"><\/iframe>
```

Replace

```
< img $1https://media.giphy.com/media/$2/giphy.gif"></img>
```

[See demo](https://regex101.com/r/Wb7ZtN/1)

Comment: Thanks. But I can achieve this with Swift 3 ?

Comment: You asked for a regex and you don't know if your language support regexes?

Comment: Swift support RegExp ! But how can achieve this with Swift 3 ?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [Code Different](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2538939/code-different) for his help !

I need to change few things for replace all occurences in my string.
Here is my code :

```
let mutableStr = NSMutableString(string: str)
let regex = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: "<\\s*(iframe).+src=\"(.+?)\".+(/iframe)", options: [])
let matches = regex.matches(in: str, options: [], range: NSMakeRange(0, mutableStr.length))

var k = matches.count - 1
while k  >= 0 {
    let match = matches[k]
    let components = mutableStr.substring(with: match.rangeAt(2)).components(separatedBy: "/")
    let newURL = "https://media.giphy.com/media/" + components.last! + "/giphy.gif"

    mutableStr.replaceCharacters(in: match.rangeAt(3), with: "/img")
    mutableStr.replaceCharacters(in: match.rangeAt(2), with: newURL)
    mutableStr.replaceCharacters(in: match.rangeAt(1), with: "img")

    k -= 1
}

print(mutableStr as String)
```

And it's work perfectly !